# Intranet Ip - Access from Custom Domain

Tags: iis-7, localhost, intranet, local, local-system

I have setup a local intranet in my office using IIS7 (Windows 7 Machine), currently it can be accessed through the PC's static IP, however I would like it so that internally it can just be accessed through an easier method, e.g typing in `http://intranet` (or something similar).

There are over 60 PC's in the office, so individually updating Host files on the PC's is not really ideal.

We don't need it to be accessible from the outside world (I.e, we don't care/want it to be an Extranet).

Any tips?

Comment: What DNS service do you run in your office?

Comment: 194.73.82.242 | 194.72.6.57 - just BT DNS servers I think, all just running through a Draytek router that does handle DHCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is to use an internal DHCP and DNS server.

Do you have a DHCP server? if you have a DHCP, then you configure it to give IP's and to also to give the DNS server IP.

This way you configure DNS Names (in the DNS server) like "intranet is at > 10.1.1.1"
And all the machines get to know the "intranet" server IP

Comment: The router handles DHCP I believe, not sure I've seen any options for assigning DNS names though.